# DatabaseReference doesnt contain definition for "GetValueAsync"

Tags: c#, android, firebase, visual-studio-code, mobile

I usually don't look for help this way, but i couldn't manage to fix on my own.

In this Android mobile app that I'm making in Visual Studio C#, my plan is to write and read data from Firebase, I managed to write successfully but I'm having trouble with reading.

When using GetValueAsync(), doesn't matter where in the code, it will pop up error that its not defined in DatabaseReference.

```
using Android.Gms.Common.Apis;
using Firebase;
using Firebase.Database;
using Java.Util.Prefs;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using static Android.Telephony.CarrierConfigManager;
using Xamarin.Essentials;



namespace AppVanillaRTB
{
    [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", MainLauncher = true)]

 
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        DatabaseReference databaseRef;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle? savedInstanceState)
        {
                       

            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

            FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(this);
            
            databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.Instance.Reference;

            
           
            Button ativar = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
            EditText Nome = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText1);

            int order;
           
            ativar.Click += async (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Nome.Text)) 
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    var newData = new UserData
                    {
                        Nome = Nome.Text,
                        Cod = 0
                    };

                    string x = "";
                    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                     {
                         string y = "";
                         x = i.ToString();
                         var dataSnapshot = await databaseRef.Child("DELIV").Child(x).Child("Nome").GetValueAsync();

                         y = dataSnapshot.ToString();
                         if (y == "") 
                         {
                             break;
                         }
                     }
                   

                    await databaseRef.Child("DELIV").Child(x).Child("Nome").SetValueAsync(newData.Nome);
                    await databaseRef.Child("DELIV").Child(x).Child("Cod").SetValueAsync(newData.Cod);
                                        

                    Xamarin.Essentials.Preferences.Set("Nome", Nome.Text);
                    Xamarin.Essentials.Preferences.Set("Code", newData.Cod);
                    //Xamarin.Essentials.Preferences.Set("Order",x);
                    
                }
            };

            
        }

       
    }
    public class UserData
   {
       public string Nome { get; set; }
       public int Cod { get; set; }
   }

   

}
```

Any help is appreciated.

(Sorry for the not so good English, it's not my mother language)

Tried reinstalling the Firebase packages, tried creating a new async method to use it and a few other tries.

Edit: For better understanding, i added the error beloew:

DatabaseReference' doesn't contain a definition for "GetValueAsync" and we couldn't find any extension method "GetValueAsync" that accepts a first argument of type 'DatabaseReference' (are you forgetting to use a directive or an assembly reference?)

Edit2: I found a workaround, instead of using Xamarin.Firebase.Database API, i changed to the FireSharp API and it worked much better, without the need of json, the problem was that i had to change the whole code, and i did.

Comment: Is `databaseRef.Child("DELIV").Child(x).Child("Nome").SetValueAsync(newData.Nome)` working?

Comment: It is, and its setting the data correctly into firebase database